# How to find the name of a variable calling a function?

Tags: javascript

```
const Button = myFunc();
```

Now from inside `myFunc`, I want to get the string `"Button"` (even before it is assigned to it). Is that possible?

**Edit**:

I see a lot of comments asking why this is even needed.
I'm creating a React component by extending an existing component and adding styles to it (via a new style element at the document `head`). I want the new class to be called by ".RedButton", for example:

```
const RedButton = extend(Button)`
  color: red;
`;

...

const extend = OriginalComponent => {
  
  const newComponentName = ... // Here I need the use of "RedButton"
  ...
};
```

Comment: that isn't possible with out parsing the javascript.

Comment: What's the point of this? The variable could be named anything, it doesn't affect how the object behaves.

Comment: This is very vague, can you provided a better example with actual code?

Comment: @Barmar there is a point... I'm trying to edit an html style element and add a new class named .Button (for example)

Comment: Why would the variable name be the same as the class?

Comment: Make the CSS class to add a parameter of `myFunc()`.

Comment: @Barmar I'd rather not... It uglifies the usage

Comment: there's no way to do what you want in JS. You could write a preprocessor that looks for all these calls and rewrites them.

Comment: @Barmar I see... Thanks